# React router change route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
<Route path="news">
  <IndexRoute component={News} />
  <Route path=":id" component={NewsCard} />
</Route>
```

I want to access this route with url like `/news-:id`. How can I do it?

I do without nesting:

```
<Route path="news-:id" component={NewsCard} />
```

Can i do it differently?

Comment: Which version of [tag:react-router] are you using?

Comment: "react-router": "^3.0.2"

Comment: hmm, Why not having the path as `news/id` ? It is more readable.

Comment: I agree with @Nicholas. You cannot nest routes and get a `-` as a delimiter instead of `/`, unless you write your own routing solution. If the `-` is a must, I would create two routes: One for `/news` and another for `/news-:id`.

Comment: Customer requirements :(

I agree with you:)

Thanks for your answers